# ¿Cómo modificar el href de un enlace con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo varios enlaces en una paginación y quiero modificarlos todos al mismo tiempo con JavaScript este es el código que tengo actualmente:

```
function agregar_busqueda_url(busqueda) {
  var enlaces = $(".paginacion a");
  var busq = "&busq=" + busqueda;
  for (var i = 0; i < enlaces.length; i++) {
    var nuevo = enlaces[i].href + busq;
    enlaces[i].setAttribute("href", nuevo);
    console.log(enlaces[i].href);
  }
}
```

En los `console.log` si se ve que cambia el enlace, pero cuando checo los elemento del `HTML` con el inspector de Chrome, los enlaces siguen teniendo el `href` original.

No se si haya algún problema porque estoy trayendo dichos enlaces de la paginación con AJAX cada vez que se produce el evento `KeyUp` en una caja de búsqueda de productos. Espero y me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Tu código sólo muestra una función de Javascript, por lo menos falta el HTML e indicar la versión de jQuery que usas. Agrega un [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede hacer también con Javascript puro del siguiente modo:

- Obtienes una referencia a todos los enlaces de la clase `paginacion` mediante `querySelectorAll`
- Abres un bucle para asignar un nuevo `href` a esos elementos.

```js
var theLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.paginacion a');

theLinks.forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com";
});
```

```html
<div class="paginacion">
      <a href="https://google.com">Click aquí 1</a><br/>
      <a href="https://google.com">Click aquí 2</a><br/>
      <a href="https://google.com">Click aquí 3</a><br/>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="no-paginacion">
      <a href="https://google.com">Este no 1</a><br/>
      <a href="https://google.com">Este no 2</a><br/>
      <a href="https://google.com">Este no 3</a><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

utilizando JQuery, lo que buscas hacer es muy simple, podes hacerlo con [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) si estas en la versión 1.6 o superior, en caso contrario, podes usar [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

En caso de que uses `prop()` te dejo un ejemplo, sin embargo, con `attr()` el código sería exactamente el mismo (sólo remplazando `prop('url','newurl')` por `attr('url','newurl')`;

```
$('.paginacion a').prop('href','http://nuevaUrl.com');
```

Te dejo un ejemplo por si no te queda claro:

```js
$('button').on('click',function()
{
   $('.ejemplo a').prop('href','http://yahoo.com.ar');
   console.log('Todos los enlaces, ahora apuntan a yahoo.com.ar!');
});
```

```html
<div class="ejemplo">
      <a href="https://google.com">Enlace 1</a><br/>
      <a href="https://google.com">Enlace 1</a><br/>
      <a href="https://google.com">Enlace 1</a><br/>
</div>

<button>Modificar!</button>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"
  integrity="sha256-fNXJFIlca05BIO2Y5zh1xrShK3ME+/lYZ0j+ChxX2DA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Saludos, éxitos!